# How does killing senators affect their mood?

Tags: disgaea-4

I know killing Senators in Disgaea 4 drops their affinity for you, but how much in absolute terms? They have a "Loathe" to "Love" scale but there's no numerical value presented in game so it's hard to tell.

Specifically, how many items do I have to give them to make up for killing them once? Will one "Must Have" item do it or does it tick them off more/less than that? I'm trying to decide if it's ever worth killing senators or if I should wait until I can bribe them.

Comment: Game tag added. And I'm going to go out on a limb here and say "killing people makes them like you less." :P

Comment: @BenBrocka Series tags are usually only applied to questions about the global stroyline. Also, as GraceNote said, it's likely that the mechanics _do_ slightly vary so you have to specify which version you care about

Comment: The amount it affects may not be the same across each game.

Comment: I'll take "Questions that get you on an FBI watch list" for $200.

Comment: "Dear Diary: Today was a bad day. I got killed again! Fortunately I was able to screw over the public with SOPA and that made me feel a bit better. I've sent the killer a link to my Amazon wishlist; hopefully we can put this nasty murder business behind us."

Comment: @MatthewRead you laugh but that is exactly how the Senate in Disgaea works

Comment: From what I read [in this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995078-disgaea-4-a-promise-unforgotten/61932690) it seems like different senators like different things, but in general they like [shoes, glasses,
orbs, muscles, angel cake and gold bars](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/995078-disgaea-4-a-promise-unforgotten/faqs/62964)?

Comment: @Gwen I know what they like, I'm just wondering how much their happiness drops when I kill them, and roughly how many "must have"/ect items it takes to counter that.

Comment: @BenBrocka If you are trying to pass a bill by force, you can try tossing all those Nay-saying senators at a higher level Yay-saying senator instead. It will merge the two, and the higher level one always wins. This method won't effect a senator's relationship value and is also an easy way to force bills before you're strong enough to kill them. Works with neutral units too.

Comment: @SaintWacko Putting a bounty on a question asking about killing senators... sure why not :)

Comment: @Krazer really? Would have thought it counted as killing them. Good to know

Comment: [I know what the Senator wants. What the Senator wants is a....](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pADR7Hx9xqk)

Comment: @BenBrocka I know for sure that Krazer's suggestion worked in the original, I don't know if they've changed or fixed that afterwards.

Comment: @yx. sounds likely possible. I usually just plowed through the senate on D3 though, but in D4 I've been more tacit...but some senators are a thorn in my side.

Comment: You're definitely right that it's hard to determine. I tended not to track the individual senator's friendship levels when I played, as they seem to be prone to random fluctuation anyway. I've found that depending on the rarity of the item and its value, a Must Have item will often bring them up 1-2 full ranks on the chart.

Comment: @Kazriko I was just wondering if it's *ever* worth killing them and what sort of repair work I'd have to do, but that's becoming less of a problem now so I think I can just skirt around the issue and not murder people.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure on Disgaea 4, but they have been the same for Disgaea 2 and 3, so I'll go off that as it shouldn't have changed much.

There really is no value set on it and there are even levels within the ranks themselves, by this I mean 1 item will not 100% set them from Strongly for to love, but if we DID give them numeric values for the argument of this question, I'll try to illustrate below how killing would effect.

Say a senator has 500 rep points, a slightly interested item would be worth 10, interested would be worth 25, very interested would be worth 50, must have! would be worth 100, and not very interested or doesn't want would change in values depending on just how much they don't want it.

Killing would probably be around -200 / -250.  If a senator loves you, and you kill him, he probably won't loathe you, but he'll most likely drop to around neutral / barely positive, which will take 2-3 or maybe even 4 must have items to make up in the long run.

Overall through my experience, never kill senators unless you're going for one those suggestions that has a 1-20% chance of success, anything higher than that I just save my game try it, if it fails, I reset and try again, but if it has extremely low chances I will bribe as many as I can and kill the rest, usually it doesn't have an overwhelming aftermath.

Comment: Hey, @Fatboi, I've edited your answer to be a little more readable.  Remember, whitespace and punctuation can help immensely.